# can I install hlint by stack without using cabal

Tags: haskell

I am trying to install HLint. The installation document says you can use cabal install hlint. But I don't have a cabal installed in my machine (Ubuntu 16.04) and it looks possible to install hlint by only using stack.
My question is if I need to add many extra-deps?
When I ran stack install hlint, it returns

```
Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in 
/home/as/proj1/stack.yaml:
- ansi-terminal-0.7.1.1
- cmdargs-0.10.18
- cpphs-1.20.8
- extra-1.6
- haskell-src-exts-1.19.1
- hscolour-1.24.1
- refact-0.3.0.2
- text-1.2.2.2
- uniplate-1.6.12
- unordered-containers-0.2.8.0
- vector-0.12.0.1
- yaml-0.8.23.3
```

Do I need to add all of them to extra-deps?  After adding some, I found I need to add more..  Am I doing something wrong ?
Thank you,
eii

Comment: After installing stack, I ran stack new proj1 and then stack setup, then stack install hlint.

Comment: Usually `hlint` is installed globally and not as part of the project (if your aim is to just have code and linting suggestions). So, I would recommend you to install it outside of the project globally. Also, since it's part of the [resolver](https://www.stackage.org/lts-9.6/package/hlint) - the installation should be smooth.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I had "resolver: ghc-8.2.1" in my stack.yaml.  I changed it to nightly-2017-10-11 then I was able to install hlint by stack globally.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem (I'm also using an M1 for the record), at the end I gave and installed [hindent](http://hindent) instead. Then I added this to my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`:

```
setlocal formatprg=hindent
```

and `gq` now formats my code. I'm still having some glitches though, but I think they're either real bugs in hindent or due to running this all on an M1.